# CSS: May I right-align an element by margin: 0 0 0 auto?

Tags: css, alignment, margin

May I right-align an element by setting margin-left

```
margin: 0 0 0 auto;
```

but not float

```
float: right;
```

?

I don't know if this is right but it works, both in Chrome and Safari.

========

A.K's answer is what I need;

And this is also helpful, via Praveen Kumar:
You can, but the support is limited. It works only in Chrome and Safari. Not even in Firefox, I guess. See, if you are going to target only Chrome browser, yes, you can. All the -webkit- based browsers support this, but not others. Choice is yours. :)

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: make right:0 in that div

Comment: you can also do padding-right:0

Comment: i don't know what you are trying to achieve but you can use **text-align:right** for this

Comment: Because center-align an element use this - margin: 0 auto; so ....

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, because of the word *"may"* and the phrase *"right-align an element"*. Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can **right-align** an element by setting `margin-left:auto`

But see the difference between `margin` and `float` results below:

[**Margin**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/margin)

> The margin CSS property sets the margin for all four sides. It is a shorthand to avoid setting each side separately with the other margin properties: margin-top, margin-right, margin-bottom and margin-left.

[**Float**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/float):

> The float CSS property specifies that an element should be taken from the normal flow and placed along the left or right side of its container, where text and inline elements will wrap around it.

[**SEE RESULT**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/2sswp/)

Comment: The OP Clearly mentioned not to use float!

Comment: @ Praveen Kumar: The OP want to know that `right-align an element by setting margin-left` is a right technique or not? So I differentiated both techniques with a result.

Answer (score 4):

#### Solution 1: Using Positioning

You can make it using **positioning** if not by floating. Have the parent element as `position: relative;` and the element as `position: absolute;` with `left: auto;` and others as `0`.

**CSS**

```
.parent {position: relative;}
.parent .child {position: absolute; left: auto; right: 0; width: 150px; height: 50px;}​​​
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        Content
    </div>
</div>​
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U3JXk/**
**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U3JXk/1/** (With Border)

#### Solution 2: Resetting Display Attributes

If you are not willing to use positioning, you can try changing the `display` attributes of the element to appear as `inline` and use `text-align` as `right`.

**CSS**

```
.parent {text-align: right;}
.parent .child {display: inline;}
/* OR */
.parent .child {display: inline-block; *display: inline; *zoom: 1;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

​
**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U3JXk/2/** 
**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U3JXk/3/** (With Border)

Comment: This is still going to take the element out of the page flow, which I assume the OP wants to avoid.

Comment: May be, just a try. Lets wait for the OP to respond. :)

Comment: Thanks, but I want to know that: May I right-align an element by margin: 0 0 0 auto? and why?

Comment: You can, but the support is limited. It works only in Chrome and Safari. Not even in Firefox, I guess. See, if you are going to target only Chrome browser, yes, you can. All the `-webkit-` based browsers support this, but not others. Choice is yours. :)

Comment: @Praveen Kumar You are right, it doesn't work in Firefox. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Margin keeps your content intact within the Flow of your content but Float layers up your content so there are chances where content may follow below it; above this Position Relative / Absolute layers it up a bit more than floating an element i.e. It takes your tags out of the content Flow and adjusted as per z-index and position L T R B values (by default:Left Top). Different browsers react differently when you adjust the alignment by Margin as it actually affects your content Flow but keeping Parent Element Float options works well for me, all it depends on the requirement.